# Regarding Summation Of data by using joins between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table and Select query displayed in image. Here I want X.Amount equals to 1000 but i got 3000

[image]

Comment: You should see the `X.Amount` value three times, but it should be `1000` in each record, not `3000`.  Are you sure this is the query you actually ran?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is right. You want to sum distinct rows of A, not for each relation A = B. You can use an aggregate or get rid of the join and use a subquery to fetch only records of A where exists at least one reference in B

Comment: Yes, I run It came like that

Answer (score 0):

A little speculation, as the numbers would match... Do you want to compare the sum of `Amount` of `TableB` with that of `TableA` for each ID? In that case you probably want to join subqueries building the sums first.

```
SELECT TableA.Amount,
       TableB.Amount
       FROM (SELECT Id,
                    sum(Amount) Amount
                    FROM TableA
                    GROUP BY Id) TableA
            INNER JOIN (SELECT Id,
                               sum(Amount) Amount
                               FROM TableB
                               GROUP BY Id) TableB
                       ON TableB.Id = TableA.Id;
```